# Is there any other ways to solve the domain of "a"?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

Assume $f(x)=|x^2 -5x| -a(x+4)$. If function $f(x)$ has just 4 roots , then what is the domain of real number $a$?

Is there any other ways to solve this?
I mean the 2 gentlemen below use $\Delta$ to find the domain.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: You can play around with this: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/c9duha226c

Comment: Thank u for your graph. Matti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mid x^2-5x\mid=\begin {cases}5x-x^2,\,x\in[0,5]\\x^2-5x,\,x\notin[0,5]\end{cases}$.

You get two quadratic equations.

For $x\in[0,5]$, we get $f(x)=-x^2+(5-a)x-4a=0\implies f$ will have two roots if the discriminant is positive.  $\Delta=(5-a)^2-4(4a)(1)=25-10a+a^2-16a=a^2-26a+25\gt0\implies a\notin [1,25]$.

I leave the other part for you.

Comment: $$ x\in(-{\infty},0], x\in(5,{\infty},],$$

Comment: Yes.  That part.

Comment: $${\Delta}=(5-a)^2+16a=a^2+6a+25\leq 0$$

Comment: That's inpossible for a like that in domain  $x\in(-{\infty},0], x\in(5,{\infty},]$.So we will only get$$a\notin (1,25)$$

Comment: $\Delta =(5+a)^2+16a=a^2+26a+25\gt0\implies a\notin [-25,-1]$.

Comment: Sorry for that dumb mistake I made before. Chris

Comment: Thank u for your correction! Chris

Answer (score 2):

1. Show that the equation $x^2-5x-a(x+4)=0$ has two solutions $ \iff a \in (- \infty,-25) \cup (-1, \infty).$
2. Show that the equation $-x^2+5x-a(x+4)=0$ has two solutions $ \iff a \in (- \infty,1) \cup (25, \infty).$

Can you take it from here ?

Comment: Can u write the detail ?I'm still confused.